# Fixing badly formatted string with number and thousands seperator

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am receiving a string with numbers, nulls, and delimiters that are the same  as characters in the numbers.  Also there are quotes around numbers that contain a comma(s).  With C#, I want to parse out the string, such that I have a nice, pipe delimited series of numbers, no commas, 2 decimal places.

I tried the standard replace, removing certain string patterns to clean it up but I can't hit every case.  I've removed the quotes first, but then I get extra numbers as the thousands separator turns into a delimiter.  I attempted to use `Regex.Replace` with wildcards but can't get anything out of it due to the multiple numbers with quotes and commas inside the quotes.

edit for Silvermind:  temp = Regex.Replace(temp, "(?:\"*,*.*\")","($1 = *.*\n)");

I don't have control over the file I receive.  I can get most of the data cleaned up.  It's when the string looks like the following, that there is a problem:

> 703.36,751.36,"1,788.36",887.37,891.37,"1,850.37",843.37,"1,549,797.36",818.36,749.36,705.36,0.00,"18,979.70",934.37

Should I look for the quote character, find the next quote character, remove commas from everything between those 2 chars, and move on?  This is where I'm headed but there has to be something more elegant out there (yes - I don't program in C# that often - I'm a DBA).

I would like to see the thousands separator removed, and no quotes.

Comment: Always show what you've tried. (Edit it into your question please)

Comment: This looks like CSV to me. Try some CSV reader/parser (such as CSVHelper) which should help you solve your parsing problem in an easy way.

Comment: This will remove commas and quotes (fixing the string): @"""|(?<=""\d[\d,]*),(?=[\d,.""])" Replace with an empty string and you have a wellformed comma separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex pattern will match all of the individual numbers in your string:

`(".*?")|(\d+(.\d+)?)`

- `(".*?")` matches things like  `"123.45"`
- `(\d+(.\d+)?)` matches things like `123.45` or `123`

From there, you can do a simple search and replace on each match to get a "clean" number.

Full code:

```
  var s = "703.36,751.36,\"1,788.36\",887.37,891.37,\"1,850.37\",843.37,\"1,549,797.36\",818.36,749.36,705.36,0.00,\"18,979.70\",934.37";

  Regex r = new Regex("(\".*?\")|(\\d+(.\\d+)?)");

  List<double> results = new List<double>();
  foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
  {
    string cleanNumber = m.Value.Replace("\"", "");
    results.Add(double.Parse(cleanNumber));
  }

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

Output:

```
703.36, 751.36, 1788.36, 887.37, 891.37, 1850.37, 843.37, 1549797.36, 818.36, 749.36, 705.36, 0, 18979.7, 934.37
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the "elegant" I was looking for.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler to solve with a parser type solution which keeps track of state.  Regex is for regular text anytime you have context it gets hard to solve with regex.  Something like this would work.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static string testString = "703.36,751.36,\"1,788.36\",887.37,891.37,\"1,850.37\",843.37,\"1,549,797.36\",818.36,749.36,705.36,0.00,\"18,979.70\",934.37";




    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool inQuote = false;
        List<string> numbersStr = new List<string>();

        int StartPos = 0;
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x = 0; x < testString.Length; x++)
        {
            if(testString[x] == '"')
            {
                inQuote = !inQuote;
                continue;
            }

            if(testString[x] == ',' && !inQuote )
            {
                numbersStr.Add(SB.ToString());
                SB.Clear();
                continue; 
            }

            if(char.IsDigit(testString[x]) || testString[x] == '.')
            {
                SB.Append(testString[x]);
            }
        }
        if(SB.Length != 0)
        {
            numbersStr.Add(SB.ToString());
        }

        var nums = numbersStr.Select(x => double.Parse(x));

        foreach(var num in nums)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I liked this better then my char-by-char approach.  The below Regex from MikeH got the elegance I was looking for.